# Reffering to a css stylesheet from an unknown, higher directory

Tags: css, stylesheet

I'm currently in the process of building my first PHP-based website. The entire website is located in the main directory: example.com

I want users to find different pages of my website by going to links like example.com/page, example.com/another_page, example.com/directory/some_page, etc. etc.

To do this, I make these directories, and add the following php-code in an index.php:

```
<?php
include("/home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/index.php");
?>
```

This works fine, the page is being included. The problem is that the stylesheet isn't. It only works in the main folder.  I tried both these HTML-snippets:

```
<link href="Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But they both don't work.

How does this work in HTML, how to access the home directory?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use . for one level up, .. for 2 levels up, ... for 3 levels up and so on.

Comment: The stylesheet is also located in the main directory, so I'd have to make a specific stylesheet for every layer, and a specific index for every layer ..

Comment: But it's fixed anyway :)

Comment: @BlueMoonProductions:  Don't forget to "accept" an answer below.  In this case, the first one submitted by aioobe would probably be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The css file is downloaded and included **on the client side**, as opposed to the php `include` statement which includes the file **on the server side**.

The path for the css should therefor "make sense" from the clients perspective and probably be specified relative to the `public_html` directory. That is, if it resides directly in the `public_html` directory the line should read

```
<link href="/Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The browser can't see all the directories under your public_html. Web servers present the browser with a document root. You need to refer to it with a `/` only:

```
<link href="/Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Also consider using mod_rewrite instead of creating directories and PHP files everywhere. I think you would find that much more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

This is your absolute path for Server-Side access:

```
<?php
include("/home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/myDirectory/Stylesheet.css");
?>
```

**However**, you want access from your Web Server for this.  The absolute path for the Web Server is as follows, where `/` is the root of your web server and `myDirectory` is a directory location off the root:

```
<link href="/myDirectory/Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```